# How to enable Two-Finger rotation on Apple Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios6-maps

How can i enable Two-Finger rotation feature that we see in New Apple Maps in iOS6?

Has anyone done this yet? Is there something in the documentation i might be able to find?

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have the rotation with the [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), this is not available as a setting in the official API.

Comment: But, the Map app of apple you can rotate the map with two fingers, at least in my iPad Mini, and I want that in my App...

Comment: If Apple does something does not mean that you can do it. The MKMapKit does not have any method for rotation. So you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The API which apple has documented does not include rotation with two-fingers, Here is the Documentation : [Two-Finger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
[mapView setRotateEnabled:YES];
```

edit: (this is new in iOS7, just putting it here in case someone finds this thread and needs the answer)