# How to enable Two-Finger rotation on Apple Map using MKMapView

Tags: iphone

I am new in iPhone, as per customer requirement I want to enable Two-Finger rotation using MKMapView. How can I enable Two-Finger rotation as we can see in Apple Maps in iOS6?

Comment: See the following link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777404/how-to-enable-two-finger-rotation-on-apple-maps

it may helps you....

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done as far as i know. The API which apple has documented does not include rotation with two fingers in MKMapView.
Here is the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation where it specifies that its not support? Bit annoyed if you can't rotate the map. Seems ridiculous to me that they allow it in their Maps application...

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
[mapView setRotateEnabled:YES];
```

This is new in iOS7.